# Stop Firebase from removing 0 from a number

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This latitude should have a '0' at the end, but whenever I add it - Firebase deletes it. Being a coordinate I need it to be exactly 51.3910 not 51.391. Any idea how I'd force Firebase to leave the '0' in there?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) you have many options, since you have not added you code, you may try a code like this to solve the issue.

```java
Firebase busCoords = mRef.child("Location");
busCoords.setValue(location.getLatitude()+ ",   "+location.getLongitude());
```

This MUST be working, but you may also try turning the number to a string, which can be done with a code like this:

```java
String numberAsString = String.valueOf( -895.25);
```

Comment: The documentation linked is for Firestore, but it looks like the asker is using the legacy [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), [which uses JSON](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree). You're correct though, storing as a string would leave the stored data "as-is".

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I changed a few things around like making it a String instead - however I found the problem was that Google had given me the incorrect coordinates to start with! - see my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Realtime Database uses JSON to store data, so will accept the following data types:

- string
- number
- boolean
- array
- JSON object
- null

The data type for your `Latitude` node will be considered a `number`, which does not support trailing or leading zeros.

Therefore, you'll need to manually pad your data when retrieving it from the database, or store it as a `string` instead.

Answer (score 0):

So having looked into it for hours, I have figured out the problem lied with Google giving me wrong coordinates when I typed in 'example coordinates'. The coordinates were not right and the coordinates I wanted didn't end in a 0!

Thank you for your help.